# In Unity how can I know which direction is the screen auto-rotated?

Tags: unity, mobile, screen

From the [`Screen.orientation`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Screen-orientation.html) description I get

> If the value is set to `ScreenOrientation.AutoRotation` then the screen will select [...] automatically as the device orientation changes.

This seems to imply that if the screen *does* auto-rotate, *then* `Screen.orientation` has been set to `ScreenOrientation.AutoRotation`.

If that's so, how can I know in which direction it has been auto-rotated?

Disabling the auto-rotation doesn't count (obviously), and I need to distinguish between `LandscapeLeft` and `LandscapeRight`, so checking height and width doesn't work either.

This should be cross-platform, without including any kind of non-C# plugin.

*(the answer, given this documentation, seems to be "you can't", but maybe I'm missing something)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be easy to distinguish between portrait and landscape by checking `Screen.height > Screen.width`.

From a display perspective you are unable to distinguish between `Portrait`/`PortraitUpsideDown` and `LandscapeLeft`/`LandscapeRight`.

However it is possible to disable any of these by setting any of the following to `false`:

- `autorotateToLandscapeLeft`
- `autorotateToLandscapeRight`
- `autorotateToPortrait`
- `autorotateToPortraitUpsideDown`

Some coverage of these display issues is [here for Android](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AndroidMobileAdvanced.html) and [here for iOS](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/iOSMobileAdvanced.html).

However you can determine the device orientation via [Input.deviceOrientation](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input-deviceOrientation.html)

Comment: Unfortunately I need the opposite: I need to distinguish betweek LandscapeLeft/LandscapeRight, and I need not to disable it. So I guess this could be summarised as "you can't"?

Comment: @Lohoris Please see edit.

Comment: Oh, `Input.deviceOrientation` might be what I need, I'll test it, thanks!

Comment: I've solved it with [`WebCamTexture.videoRotationAngle`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WebCamTexture-videoRotationAngle.html). I'm not posting this as an answer, since I don't know why I didn't use `Input.deviceOrientation`.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of some method, that will return ScreenOrientation from Input.deviceOrientation. But because sometimes deviceOrientation can't be distinguished (e.g. [diagonal or parallel to ground](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/DeviceOrientation.html)) that method will return null in that case:

```
private ScreenOrientation? DeviceOrientationToScreenOrientation(DeviceOrientation deviceOrientation)
        {
            switch (deviceOrientation)
            {
                case DeviceOrientation.Portrait:
                    if (Screen.autorotateToPortrait)
                    {
                        return ScreenOrientation.Portrait;
                    }
                    break;
                case DeviceOrientation.PortraitUpsideDown:
                    if (Screen.autorotateToPortraitUpsideDown)
                    {
                        return ScreenOrientation.PortraitUpsideDown;
                    }
                    break;
                case DeviceOrientation.LandscapeLeft:
                    if (Screen.autorotateToLandscapeLeft)
                    {
                        return ScreenOrientation.LandscapeLeft;
                    }
                    break;
                case DeviceOrientation.LandscapeRight:
                    if (Screen.autorotateToLandscapeRight)
                    {
                        return ScreenOrientation.LandscapeRight;
                    }
                    break;
            }
            return null;
        }
```

So we need to wait, until Input.deviceOrientation will return something, we can distinguish. In my game I need to freeze screen from flipping between landscapeLeft & landscapeRight when in game, but allow when in menu. So I start checking for Input.deviceOrientation each half-second after hiding menu. That's how it can be implemented using UniRx:

```
private void OnEnable()
{
Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500))
                .Select(_ => DeviceOrientationToScreenOrientation(Input.deviceOrientation))
                .First(orientation => orientation.HasValue)
                .SubscribeUntilDisable(this, orientation =>
                {
                    Screen.orientation = orientation.Value;
                });
}
```